# How does TMemo eat an escape key, when TEdit doesn't?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to stop a `TMemo` (and also `TRichEdit`) control from eating `Escape` keys.

If the user is focused in a `TEdit`, pressing `Escape` will trigger the form to do what the form does when the user presses escape. If the user is focused in a `TMemo`, pressing escape is eaten by the `TMemo`.

Of course i could do the hack:

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
    if Key = #27 then
    begin
       //figure out how to send a key to the form
    end;
end;
```

But that is not ideal (i have to handle the escape key, rather than letting the form handle it).

Of course i could do the hack:

```
Form1.KeyPreview := True;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   if Key = #27 then
   begin
      //Figure out how to invoke what the form was going to do when the user presses escape
   end;
end;
```

But that is not ideal (i have to handle the escape key, rather than letting the form handle it).

### So we'll answer the question rather than the problem

Instead we'll take this opportunity to learn something. How is it that a `TMemo` is even ***receiving*** a keyPress event associated with [the escape key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character), when a `TEdit` doesn't:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
    if Key = #27 then
    begin
        //never happens
    end;
end;
```

The `TEdit` and `TMemo` are the same Windows [`EDIT` common control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

### Why does escape bypass the form's **KeyPreview**

If i turn on the form's `KeyPreview`, and the user presses `Escape` while focused in a `TEdit` box, and a button's `Cancel` property is set, the form closes and:

- the `Edit1.KeyPress` event is not triggered
- the `Form1.KeyPress` event is not triggered

If an Action is created, whose `Shortcut` is `Esc`, then no `KeyPress` event is raised, no matter what control the user is focused in.

**tl;dr**: Where is the `TMemo.WantEscape` property?

Comment: You can always catch the WM_KeyDown (or WM_SysKeyDown, don't remember)  message. This is the first place where the event will be triggered and you can set `Handled := True` to consume it. Honestly, I find the VCL `OnKeyPress` events to have a very weird behaviour (specially if you use form's `KeyPreview`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is controlled by the handling of the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message. For a memo that looks like this:

```
procedure TCustomMemo.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  inherited;
  if FWantTabs then Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTTAB
  else Message.Result := Message.Result and not DLGC_WANTTAB;
  if not FWantReturns then
    Message.Result := Message.Result and not DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
end;
```

For an edit control the VCL does not implement special handling for `WM_GETDLGCODE` and the underlying Windows edit control handles it.

In a standard Win32 app the Windows dialog manager sends the `WM_GETDLGCODE` messages. But Delphi is not built on top of the dialog manager, and so the VCL is in charge of sending `WM_GETDLGCODE`. It does so in the `CN_KEYDOWN` handler. The code looks like this:

```
Mask := 0;
case CharCode of
  VK_TAB:
    Mask := DLGC_WANTTAB;
  VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT, VK_UP, VK_DOWN:
    Mask := DLGC_WANTARROWS;
  VK_RETURN, VK_EXECUTE, VK_ESCAPE, VK_CANCEL:
    Mask := DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
end;
if (Mask <> 0) and
  (Perform(CM_WANTSPECIALKEY, CharCode, 0) = 0) and
  (Perform(WM_GETDLGCODE, 0, 0) and Mask = 0) and
  (GetParentForm(Self).Perform(CM_DIALOGKEY,
  CharCode, KeyData) <> 0) then Exit;
```

Notice that `VK_RETURN`, `VK_EXECUTE`, `VK_ESCAPE` and `VK_CANCEL` are all lumped together. This means that a VCL control has to decide whether or not to process these keys itself, or let the form handle them in its `CM_DIALOGKEY` handler.

As you can see from `TCustomMemo.WMGetDlgCode` you can influence that choice with the `WantReturns` property. So, you can persuade the VCL to let the form handle <kbd>ESC</kbd> by simply setting `WantReturns` on the memo to `False`. But that also stops the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key reaching memo and makes it rather tricky for the user of the memo to enter new lines. They have to do it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

In fact `WantReturns` should really have been named `WantReturnsAndEscapesAndExecutesAndCtrlBreaks`. The VCL designers could have implemented a `WantEscapes` property but it's just not there.

So you are left handling it yourself one way or another. Personally, I do so with my own derived memo control. It overrides the `KeyDown` method and does this:

```
procedure TMyMemo.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
  Message: TCMDialogKey;
begin
  inherited;
  if (Key=VK_ESCAPE) and (Shift*[ssShift..ssCtrl])=[]) then begin
    Form := GetParentForm(Self);
    if Assigned(Form) then begin
      // we need to dispatch this key press to the form so that it can 'press' 
      // any buttons with Cancel=True
      Message.Msg := CM_DIALOGKEY;
      Message.CharCode := VK_ESCAPE;
      Message.KeyData := 0;
      Message.Result := 0;
      Form.Dispatch(Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Another way to achieve this is to handle `CM_WANTSPECIALKEY` and `WM_GETDLGCODE`. Here's a crude interposer that illustrates the technique:

```
type
  TMemo = class(StdCtrls.TMemo)
  protected
    procedure CMWantSpecialKey(var Msg: TCMWantSpecialKey); message CM_WANTSPECIALKEY;
    procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Msg: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
  end;

procedure TMemo.CMWantSpecialKey(var Msg: TCMWantSpecialKey);
begin
  case Msg.CharCode of
  VK_ESCAPE:
    Msg.Result := 0;
  VK_RETURN, VK_EXECUTE, VK_CANCEL:
    Msg.Result := 1;
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;

procedure TMemo.WMGetDlgCode(var Msg: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  inherited;
  Msg.Result := Msg.Result and not DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
end;
```

Comment: So it really is something deep in the guts of the `EDIT` control that handles them itself?

Comment: @Ian I think that is now better.